# 0-1 Knapsack algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Is the following 0-1 Knapsack problem solvable:

- 'float' positive values and
- 'float' weights (can be positive or negative)
- 'float' capacity of the knapsack > 0

I have on average < 10 items, so I'm thinking of using a brute force implementation. However, I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Did you really mean *solvable*, or *solvable efficiently*?

Comment: If you don't need an exact answer, you might look into simulated annealing..

Comment: 2^10 is 1024. Definitely brute force it, even if there is a "better" way it will almost certainly be far slower.

Comment: So, what's the difference between the "positive values" and the "weights"? What is it you're trying to hit?

Comment: @McKay: Each item has a value and a weight.  We want to maximise the sum of the values such that the sum of the weights is <= knapsack capacity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a relatively simple binary program.

I'd suggest brute force with pruning.  If at any time you exceed the allowable weight, you don't need to try combinations of additional items, you can discard the whole tree.

Oh wait, you have **negative** weights?  Include all negative weights always, then proceed as above for the positive weights.  Or do the negative weight items also have negative value?

Include all negative weight items with positive value.  Exclude all items with positive weight and negative value.

For negative weight items with negative value, subtract their weight (increasing the knapsack capavity) and use a pseudo-item which represents *not* taking that item.  The pseudo-item will have positive weight and value.  Proceed by brute force with pruning.

```
class Knapsack
{
    double bestValue;
    bool[] bestItems;
    double[] itemValues;
    double[] itemWeights;
    double weightLimit;

    void SolveRecursive( bool[] chosen, int depth, double currentWeight, double currentValue, double remainingValue )
    {
        if (currentWeight > weightLimit) return;
        if (currentValue + remainingValue < bestValue) return;
        if (depth == chosen.Length) {
            bestValue = currentValue;
            System.Array.Copy(chosen, bestItems, chosen.Length);
            return;
        }
        remainingValue -= itemValues[depth];
        chosen[depth] = false;
        SolveRecursive(chosen, depth+1, currentWeight, currentValue, remainingValue);
        chosen[depth] = true;
        currentWeight += itemWeights[depth];
        currentValue += itemValues[depth];
        SolveRecursive(chosen, depth+1, currentWeight, currentValue, remainingValue);
    }

    public bool[] Solve()
    {
        var chosen = new bool[itemWeights.Length];
        bestItems = new bool[itemWeights.Length];
        bestValue = 0.0;
        double totalValue = 0.0;
        foreach (var v in itemValues) totalValue += v;
        SolveRecursive(chosen, 0, 0.0, 0.0, totalValue);
        return bestItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think pruning is possibly bad idea? It adds overhead (in checking), and doesn't save much time, but it does depend on how likely overfill is, especially if you also have to put items into bins based on positive negative weight.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! How would the algorithm change if an additional constraint is to be fulfilled: limit the selection to up to 5 items out of the total number of items ? Thanks again.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Check again, there is no subtraction.  The prior value is restored from the call stack (the caller has an unmodified copy).

Comment: @alhazen, that's just a second kind of "weight".  Add a `currentCount` parameter and a `countLimit` field.

Comment: this code runs in 1 millisecond on the same dataset as mine (100 ms for the batch of 10k), but I still need to change mine to actually solve knapsack (instead of target sum), so it's not actually a fair comparison, but this is faster.

Comment: @BenVoigt  So I updated my code, and now it's actually solving this version of knapsack.  And I'm getting "better" values than you, i.e. I'm fitting things of higher values in my sack than you are, when we're running on the same set. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Maybe you are? Care to look mine over. It should be rather simple. Yours will take further deconstructing to ensure that it's covering all paths.

Comment: @McKay: Mine only works for positive weight/positive value lists; it assumes that the preprocessing described in my answer has already been done.  If you put in only positive weights, do we still get different answers?  It probably would be good to generate weights and values uniformly between say 100 and 1000, and have a non-zero capacity as well.

Comment: Yeah, I tested with non-zero capacity, I'll try with larger size values too.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the negative weight is throwing off your algorithm. Maybe you should add some preprocessing code to handle those cases?

Comment: And it looks like my brute force solution runs in half the time as the recursive solution (even presuming cases where preprocessing is uneeded).

Comment: *"Include all negative weights always"* - you can turn it into a problem with all non-negative weights by subtracting the smallest value from all weights

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: No can do.  How much would you adjust the knapsack capacity to keep the problem equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, brute force it. This is an NP-Complete problem, but that shouldn't matter because you will have less than 10 items. Brute forcing won't be problematic.

```
        var size = 10;
        var capacity = 0;
        var permutations = 1024;
        var repeat = 10000;

        // Generate items
        float[] items = new float[size];
        float[] weights = new float[size];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            items[i] = (float)rand.NextDouble();
            weights[i] = (float)rand.NextDouble();
            if (rand.Next(2) == 1)
            {
                weights[i] *= -1;
            }
        }

        // solution
        int bestPosition= -1;

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();            
        sw.Start();

        // for perf testing
        //for (int r = 0; r < repeat; r++)
        {
            var bestValue = 0d;

            // solve
            for (int i = 0; i < permutations; i++)
            {
                var total = 0d;
                var weight = 0d;
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if (((i >> j) & 1) == 1)
                    {
                        total += items[j];
                        weight += weights[j];
                    }
                }

                if (weight <= capacity && total > bestValue)
                {
                    bestPosition = i;
                    bestValue = total;
                }
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        sw.Elapsed.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I think your code returns the first valid combination that satisfies the constraints, rather than the one whose total value is as large as possible (and constraints satisfied of course).

Comment: It is a form of pruning. But if you'd like to code up a more optimal solution. Feel free. This code takes 650 microseconds to run on my box. It doesn't seem like it would be a problem to run this without further optimizations.

Comment: Drat, I'm thinking of a different version of the knapsack problem.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to perf-test my recursive solution, since you already have the test framework?

Comment: @BenVoigt Doesn't compile. Care to fix it?

Comment: @McKay: Now fixed, I think.  At least it compiles, except for missing `Main`.

Comment: This code doesn't solve the knapsack problem I'm afraid: -1.  Also it's both simpler and much faster to use bitwise operations than generating a binary digit string.  In C you could just replace `if (splitOut[j] == '1')` with `if ((i >> j) & 1)`, I'm sure the syntax is similar in C#.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yeah, that's lazyness.

Comment: Thank you for the update McKay. This is a nice and simple implementation that works well with negative and positive weights. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

If you can only have positive values then every item with a negative weight must go in.

Then I guess you could calculate Value/Weight Ratio, and brute force the remaining combinations based on that order, once you get one that fits you can skip the rest.

The problem may be that the grading and sorting is actually more expensive than just doing all the calculations.

There will obviously be a different breakeven point based on the size and distribution of the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class KnapSackSolver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // number of items
    int W = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); // maximum weight of knapsack

    int[] profit = new int[N + 1];
    int[] weight = new int[N + 1];

    // generate random instance, items 1..N
    for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
        profit[n] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        weight[n] = (int) (Math.random() * W);
    }

    // opt[n][w] = max profit of packing items 1..n with weight limit w
    // sol[n][w] = does opt solution to pack items 1..n with weight limit w
    // include item n?
    int[][] opt = new int[N + 1][W + 1];
    boolean[][] sol = new boolean[N + 1][W + 1];

    for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
        for (int w = 1; w <= W; w++) {

            // don't take item n
            int option1 = opt[n - 1][w];

            // take item n
            int option2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            if (weight[n] <= w)
                option2 = profit[n] + opt[n - 1][w - weight[n]];

            // select better of two options
            opt[n][w] = Math.max(option1, option2);
            sol[n][w] = (option2 > option1);
        }
    }

    // determine which items to take
    boolean[] take = new boolean[N + 1];
    for (int n = N, w = W; n > 0; n--) {
        if (sol[n][w]) {
            take[n] = true;
            w = w - weight[n];
        } else {
            take[n] = false;
        }
    }

    // print results
    System.out.println("item" + "\t" + "profit" + "\t" + "weight" + "\t"
            + "take");
    for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
        System.out.println(n + "\t" + profit[n] + "\t" + weight[n] + "\t"
                + take[n]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Time Complexity is O(NW) and space complexity is also O(NW)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Main{
    static int max(inta,int b)
    {
      if(a>b)
        return a;
      else
        return b;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      int n,i,cap,j,t=2,w;
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of values  ");
      n=sc.nextInt();
      int solution[]=new int[n];
      System.out.println("Enter the capacity of the knapsack :- ");
      cap=sc.nextInt();
      int v[]=new int[n+1];
      int wt[]=new int[n+1];
      System.out.println("Enter the values  ");
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
        v[i]=sc.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("Enter the weights  ");
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
        wt[i]=sc.nextInt();
      }
      int knapsack[][]=new int[n+2][cap+1];
      for(i=1;i<n+2;i++)
      {
        for(j=1;j<n+1;j++)
        {
          knapsack[i][j]=0;
        }
      }
      /*for(i=1;i<n+2;i++)
         {
           for(j=wt[1]+1;j<cap+2;j++)
           {
              knapsack[i][j]=v[1];
           }
         }*/
      int k;
      for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
      {
         for(j=1;j<cap+1;j++)
         {
         /*if(i==1||j==1)
           {
            knapsack[i][j]=0;
           }*/
           if(wt[i]>j)
           {
             knapsack[i][j]=knapsack[i-1][j];
           }
           else
           {
              knapsack[i][j]=max(knapsack[i-1][j],v[i]+knapsack[i-1][j-wt[i]]);
           }
         }
    }
    //for displaying the knapsack
     for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<cap+1;j++)
       {
         System.out.print(knapsack[i][j]+" ");
       }
       System.out.print("\n");
     }
     w=cap;k=n-1;
     j=cap;
     for(i=n;i>0;i--)
     {
       if(knapsack[i][j]!=knapsack[i-1][j])
        {
          j=w-wt[i];
          w=j; 
          solution[k]=1;
          System.out.println("k="+k);
          k--;
       }
       else
       {
         solution[k]=0;
         k--;
       }
    }
    System.out.println("Solution for given knapsack is :- ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       System.out.print(solution[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.print("  =>  "+knapsack[n][cap]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using Dynamic Programming. Below code can help you solve the 0/1 Knapsack problem using Dynamic Programming.

```
    internal class knapsackProblem
    {
    private int[] weight;
    private int[] profit;
    private int capacity;
    private int itemCount;
    private int[,] data;

    internal void GetMaxProfit()
    {
        ItemDetails();

        data = new int[itemCount, capacity + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < capacity + 1; j++)
            {
                int q = j - weight[i] >= 0 ? data[i - 1, j - weight[i]] + profit[i] : 0;

                if (data[i - 1, j] > q)
                {
                    data[i, j] = data[i - 1, j];
                }
                else
                {
                    data[i, j] = q;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"\nMax profit can be made : {data[itemCount-1, capacity]}");
        IncludedItems();
    }

    private void ItemDetails()
    {
        Console.Write("\nEnter the count of items to be inserted : ");
        itemCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) + 1;
        Console.WriteLine();

        weight = new int[itemCount];
        profit = new int[itemCount];

        for (int i = 1; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"Enter weight of item {i} : ");
            weight[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write($"Enter the profit on the item {i} : ");
            profit[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.Write("\nEnter the capacity of the knapsack : ");
        capacity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    private void IncludedItems()
    {
        int i = itemCount - 1;
        int j = capacity;

        while(i > 0)
        {
            if(data[i, j] == data[i - 1, j])
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Item {i} : Not included");
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Item {i} : Included");
                j = j - weight[i];
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```