# sum up an array of integers in C#

Tags: c#

I want the sum of the numbers in the array and does not exceed 1002 how can I fix it?
it is not needful to sum all numbers, but only those who qualify

I do it that way but I think it's not the right way

```
 List<int> list = new List<int> { 4, 900, 500, 498, 4 };
        int sum = list.Skip(2).Take(3).Sum();
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Why the `Skip` and `Take`? Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: `int sum = list.Where(x => x< 1002).Sum();`

Comment: In your testcode there are no values that exceed the 1002-limit. So what exactcly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want the sum of all numbers that do not exceed 1002 or the sum until you have a number higher than 1002?

Comment: You are looking for a variation of a `knapsack problem` solving algorithm

Comment: the sum until i reach 1002 if i sum 500,498,4 then i'll reach it

Comment: But doesn´t already 4, 900 and 500 exceed this limit? Or do you need the exact value 1002?

Comment: yes I need the exact value 1002

Comment: So you want to sum any arbitrary elements from your list and check if any of those permutations equals 1002? Why not simply output 1002 on the console then?

Comment: wondering if it would be solved by having an array but an if statement ??
type if (x <= 1002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you want... If you want to sum some numbers so that the sum stops summing when it reaches 1002 you can:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 4, 900, 500, 498, 4 };
var lst = list.Skip(2).Take(3);

int sum = 0;

foreach (int num in lst)
{
    int sum2 = sum + num;

    if (sum2 > 1002)
    {
        break;
    }

    sum = sum2;
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

or you can

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 4, 900, 500, 498, 4 };
var lst = list.Skip(2).Take(3);

int sum = 0;

foreach (int num in lst)
{
    sum += num;

    if (sum >= 1002)
    {
        break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

The first one will stop if by adding a number it would go over 1002, while the second will stop AFTER reaching 1002.

Note that both of these can't be easily done directly in LINQ.

Comment: However none of those approaches will stop when the sum should be *exactly* 1002 what I suppose the OP needs.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If he wants to solve the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) then that is another problem :-)

Comment: I think OP `Skip` and `Take` was an attempt to solve the problem. P.S.:  and some random [knapsack problem solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8125309/1997232).